# Deshabilitar opción de dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito deshabilitar una opción de un select, el cual ya logro realizar. Sin embargo cuando quiero obtener el valor de la opción deshabilitada no me lo permite ya que me indica que su valor es nulo. Quiero saber si hay alguna forma de hacer no seleccionable una opción y que pueda tomar el valor de esta cuando lo necesite.

```
//deshabilito
$("#cboPuesto option[value='" + puesto + "']").attr("disabled",
"disabled");


//obtengo mi valor
var puesto = $('tr[id-renglon="' + i + '"]').find('td select').val();
puesto = null
```

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Me imagino que la mayúscula del nombre de la variable es un error de dedo al ponerlo aquí en Stackoverflow? Por otro lado, cuando deshabilitas la opción no la estás poniendo como el valor seleccionado de tu opción, al menos como se aprecia por el código que has puesto, si se puede agregar más y también HTML sería mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre y me sirvio... gracias..

```
puesto= $('tr[id-renglon="' + i+'"]').find('option[disabled]:selected').val();
```